# Multi-line NSTextFields

Tags: cocoa, macos, nstextfield

I want to know how to do something like Adium does, where when you type more text than the field can handle it expands into a new line.  Like this:

[image]

Either how can I do this, or where in the Adium source code can I find this?

Answer (score 2):

The view in Adium is AIMessageEntryTextView, plus its superclasses AISendingTextView and AITextViewWithPlaceholder, and the actual resizing (as opposed to figuring out the right size as a hypothetical ideal) is done by AIMessageViewController in response to `AIViewDesiredSizeDidChangeNotification`.

Do note that Adium is licensed under GPLv2, so unless you intend to use the same license when releasing your own project, you can't lift any of Adium's code for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what Adium itself does there.
But I am pretty sure that you could just use NSTextView.

You can find it at the Apple Developer website.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Furthermore this Tech note for using NSTextField, if anyone wants to do the extra work. ;-)
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1454/_index.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would rather try using NSTextField, but if needs be I could use this.

Comment: The difference between what Adium does and a plain NSTextView is that when the user types more than one line's worth of text (either by soft wrapping or by inserting a character that breaks the line), Adium will automatically resize the text view upward to fit it. That's what the questioner is asking about, and NSTextView by itself does not have this auto-resizing behavior.